# Year of Masters degree completion or cgpa?

Tags: phd, graduate-admissions

Is it better if I take and a B+ grade and my gpa improves little from 3.44 but the date of completion on my degree will be 2019 or is it better if I take an A grade and my cgpa becomes 3.55 but I get 2020 written on my degree? Incase I apply for further studies abroad
Is cgpa more important or the time period of degree completion

Comment: Those are  both small differences.  Is there a difference in cost?

Comment: Please explain: a) the terms gpa and cgpa, b) what you mean by better, c) what 3.44 and 3.55 mean, d) your country.